# Separate a massive line into multiple lines to create a dataframe from a HTML?

Tags: html, r, dataframe

I am currently working on reading an HTML file of [this web page](https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/) into R and processing it to extract useful data that creates a new dataframe.

Visual inspection of the web page text shows that the lines that contain data values all starts with '< td >'. So here is my code so far:

```
thepage<-readLines('https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/')

dataline <- grep('<td>', thepage)
dataline
```

This returns:

```
11
```

Which tells me all the data is in line 11. So I did this:

```
data <- thepage[11]
datalines <- grep('<td>', data)
datalines
```

This returns:

```
1
```

Which isn't helpful at all as "data" is still one massive line. How do I split this massive lines into multiple lines? My preferred dataframe would look something like this:

[image]

[image]

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
    
url <- 'https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/'

pg <- xml2::read_html(url) %>%
  rvest::html_table() %>%
  .[[1]]
```